# overlapping colors with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to recreate the letterboxd logo with HTML and CSS. I'm having trouble achieving the overlapping circles effect where the colors blend together to become darker at the intersections of the circles. Is there a way I can manipulate the z-index and/or opacity to acheive this effect? Thank you.

HTML:

```
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.circles {
    display: flex;

    .circle {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        border-radius: 50%;

        &:first-child {
            background: #FF8000;
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
            background: #05E156;
            transform: translateX(-5px);
            z-index: 2;
        }

        &:nth-child(3) {
            background: #40BCF4;
            transform: translateX(-10px);
        }
    }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/afewgoodben/pen/JjXBNEW)

Desired effect:

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `opacity` to the `.circle` class, for example:

```
.circle {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

You probably gonna need to play around with the `z-index` to tell each in what order to stack to achieve the desired effect.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Ok, so if I want to maintain these same colors but also have opacity I would need to start with darker colors then lower the opacity until I get to my current colors?

Comment: Exactly. I would play around with the colors in the Chrome or FF Dev Tools until you get the right shade with the opacity.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use `mix-blend-mode`. It's not quite what you're after and the support isn't 100%, but I think it's the best you can do with just CSS.

```css
.circles {
  display: flex;
}

.circle {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #99AEBA;
}

.circle:first-child {
  background: #FF8000;
}

.circle:nth-child(2) {
  background: #05E156;
  transform: translateX(-5px);
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.circle:nth-child(3) {
  background: #40BCF4;
  transform: translateX(-10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

If you want it exactly as your picture, I'd suggest using SVG instead. Check out [Vectr](https://vectr.com/) if you're interested. It's free and really easy to use.

Comment: `mix-blend-mode` looks like it will work nicely, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add z-index the way you are stacking div and add opacity with background-color.

```css
 .circles {
  display: flex;
}
.circles .circle {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #99aeba;
}
.circles .circle:first-child {
  background-color: rgba(225, 128, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}
.circles .circle:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: rgba(5, 255, 86, 0.5);
  transform: translateX(-7px);
  z-index: 2;
}
.circles .circle:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rgba(64, 188, 244, 0.5);
  transform: translateX(-15px);
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers mentioned using opacity for 3 circles,
But i think only the middle circle is semi transparent and it's on top of the two others.